# Do apps instaled via dpkg get updated?

Tags: updates, dpkg

I downloaded application which I did not add repository for (chrome or maxthon) and installed it via Software Center / dpkg (without adding the repo).

Do those apps get updated automatically?

Comment: that's what i get for: cat google-chrome.list cat: google-chrome.list: No such file or directory sorry if that's not the way you do it, my command line knowledge is very limited

Comment: You should not post comment as answsers, actually to see the google-chrome.list (if you installed chrome of course) it's `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list`

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please, could you put some of your time to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Deb packages directly downloaded and manually installed will not usually get updated as most of the time they don't even exist in the Ubuntu repositories.

However for Chrome, it's a bit different as during the package installation (even with a low-level package manager like `dpkg -i`) a new entry is created in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` to set up the update process:

```
$ cat google-chrome.list
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

Finally it only depends on the package itself but consider Chrome as an exception.

Usually when I need to manually install deb packages using `dpkg` it's because it need to install new package versions on older releases and I know that they won't get any (backport) updates. It's rare and should be reserved for experienced users.